# Проблема с кириллицей в CMS Q2A

Tags: html

Запустил CMS Question2Answer у себя на сайте. Подровнял дизайн, работает неплохо и стабильно. Но недавно заметил проблему: некоторый текст преобразуется в кодировки символов, а некоторый - нет.

Например я пишу слово "Являюсь", а после сохранения оно становится такого вида

```
&#1071;&#1074;&#1083;&#1103;&#1102;&#1089;&#1100;
```

Насколько я знаю, поисковики не сильно жалуют это. Может кто то сталкивался? Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

У меня подобная проблема была, все через плагин Ultimate SEO , я просто удалил его.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.